# How to grant access to /var/run to postgres on CentOS?

Tags: centos, permissions, postgresql, httpd, systemd

After installing `postgres-9.3` via `yum` in my `CentOS 7`, its default configuration puts socket in `/tmp` directory. I have `httpd` (installed via `yum` as well) which is by default managed by `system.d` with `PrivateTmp` option enabled. This means that any web application running on `httpd` can't access `/tmp` so connect to `postgres`. I have changed postgres configuration so it should put its socket in `/var/run/postgres` just like in `Ubuntu`.

Now the problem is, that `postgres` doesn't have enough privileges to write to `/var/run`. My first though was to do just:

```
chown postgres:postgres /var/run/postgres
```

But `/var/run` directory is cleaned after reboot so this won't work. My question is:

**How to grant access to `/var/run/postgres` for `postgres` user in such a way that will persist reboots?** I don't want to change socket location and I don't want to change `httpd`'s `system.d` configuration. I just want `postgres` to be able to write to `/var/run/postgres`. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the socket is only in `/tmp` on CentOS 7?

Recent versions of Fedora have two copies of the socket, one in `/run/postgresql` (which is where `/var/run/postgresql` is really located after links are resolved) which is the preferred version on modern systems, and one in `/tmp` for legacy clients that expect to find it there.

In any case if you do need to ensure the directory is created at boot then use a `tmpfiles.d` file, like `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf` which ships in Fedora and contains:

`d /var/run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -`

Answer (score 1):

The directory `/var/run` is a symbolic link to `/run` in CentOS 7.
The socket directory for PostgreSQL is `/run/postgresql`. It is a temporary directory, created at boot time.

With the advent of systemd, a new mechanism called **systemd-tmpfiles** has been introduced to manage temporary files and directories.

Systemd-tmpfiles creates temporary directories during boot and sets their owner, group and permissions. CentOS 7 has the systemd-tmpfiles configuration for PostgreSQL in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql-96.conf`. By default, the file contains the following line:

> `d /run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -`

You can change permissions, owner and group by editing that line. The recommended way to make such changes, however, is not to directly edit files under `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/`, but to copy configuration files over to `/etc/tmpfiles.d/`, and make the necessary changes in that copy instead.

Comment: The man page, `man tmpfiles.d`:https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html, explains, notably: "Files in `/etc/tmpfiles.d` override files with the same name in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d`", which, combined with the fact that `/etc/` is a more standard place for configuration files, is why your recommendation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your desired commands in /etc/rc.local file, and they will be executed at the end of each booting process.